# vi(vim)で完全にカーソルキーを無効化させたい

Tags: vim

学生にviを学習させたいのですが、カーソルキーを使うことを抑制するためのvimrc周辺を教えて下さい。

最終的には`chattr +i`で普通には削除できなくする予定です。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

こんなのはどうでしょうか。

### キーマッピング: クラシック

.vimrc ファイル

```
vnoremap  <Up>     <nop>
vnoremap  <Down>   <nop>
vnoremap  <Left>   <nop>
vnoremap  <Right>  <nop>
inoremap  <Up>     <nop>
inoremap  <Down>   <nop>
inoremap  <Left>   <nop>
inoremap  <Right>  <nop>
noremap   <Up>     <nop>
noremap   <Down>   <nop>
noremap   <Left>   <nop>
noremap   <Right>  <nop>
```

### キーマッピング: ステータスメッセージ

`<nop>` より、`<Esc>` にマッピングしして、メッセージを付けたものが以下です。
`Backspace` も無効にすると、より強い成長が見込めるかもしれません。

.vimrc ファイル

```
let g:arrowWarning = "Use [h][j][k][l] to Move!!!"
fun! ShowWarning(message)
    echo a:message
endfun
nnoremap <buffer> <Left> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <Right> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <Up> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <Down> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <Left> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <Right> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <Up> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <Down> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <Left> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <Right> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <Up> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <Down> <Esc>:call ShowWarning(g:arrowWarning)<CR>
set backspace=0
```

### キーマッピング: ドラゴン

yosh さんに頂いた指摘コメントに従ってヒントを追加し、よりユーザーに優しくしました。
予め、 `cowsay` と `sl` をシステムにインストールしてください。

- Ubuntu / Debian: `sudo apt-get cowsay sl`
- Mac OS X (brew): `brew install cowsay sl`

.vimrc ファイル

```
function TeachKey(message)
    let summon = join(["!clear; cowsay -f dragon ", a:message, "を押すのだ"])
    exec summon
endfun
nnoremap <buffer> <Left> <Esc>:call TeachKey('h')<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <Right> <Esc>:call TeachKey('l')<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <Up> <Esc>:call TeachKey('k')<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <Down> <Esc>:call TeachKey('j')<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <PageUp> <Esc>:call TeachKey('Ctrl+B')<CR>
nnoremap <buffer> <PageDown> <Esc>:call TeachKey('Ctrl+F')<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <Left> <Esc>:call TeachKeyBi)ding('h')<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <Right> <Esc>:call TeachKey('l')<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <Up> <Esc>:call TeachKey('k')<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <Down> <Esc>:call TeachKey('j')<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <PageUp> <Esc>:call TeachKey('Ctrl+B')<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <PageDown> <Esc>:call TeachKey('Ctrl+F')<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <Left> <Esc>:call TeachKeyBi)ding('h')<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <Right> <Esc>:call TeachKey('l')<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <Up> <Esc>:call TeachKey('k')<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <Down> <Esc>:call TeachKey('j')<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <PageUp> <Esc>:call TeachKey('Ctrl+B')<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <PageDown> <Esc>:call TeachKey('Ctrl+F')<CR>

nnoremap <buffer> <Del> <Esc>:<C-u>!sl<CR>
inoremap <buffer> <Del> <Esc>:<C-u>!sl<CR>
vnoremap <buffer> <Del> <Esc>:<C-u>!sl<CR>

set backspace=0
```

**追記**: 慣れたら次はこれで・・・

.vimrc ファイル

```
noremap h <nop>
noremap j <nop>
noremap k <nop>
noremap l <nop>
```

Comment: `noremap <Left> :<C-u>!sl<CR>`

Answer (score 13):

vimrc だけでやろうとすると unmap できちゃうので要求を完全には満たせないでしょうけど、やるならばこんな感じでしょうか。

```
noremap  <up>    <nop>
noremap  <left>  <nop>
noremap  <right> <nop>
noremap  <down>  <nop>
noremap! <up>    <nop>
noremap! <left>  <nop>
noremap! <right> <nop>
noremap! <down>  <nop>
```

4つのカーソルキーをそれぞれ `<nop>` にマップしてしまいます。
`noremap` と `noremap!` では適用されるモードが多少異なりますので、
Vim に付属のヘルプで `:help map-overview` あたりを参照していただければ。

Comment: ありがとうございます、<nop>でやればいいのか。ヘルプも確認してみます。
古に鬼教官モードがあったのですが、あれの再現が理想型…